# Is Mongoose support Set data type?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I wanna store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references. is possible? For example:

```js
const activity = mongoose.Schema({
   participants : {
        type: Set, // <-- is possible?
        required: true,
   },
   // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of now it supports following data types in the latest version[5.6.3].

> String,
>   Number,
>   Date,
>   Buffer,
>   Boolean,
>   Mixed,
>   ObjectId,
>   Array,
>   Decimal128,
>   Map

For more info on mongoose schema, please refer [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

For data types supported by mongoDB, refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `$addToSet` operator while updating that field.
For example:

```
const likeBook = async (req, res) => {
    const {id: bookID} = req.params
    const authorId = req.user.userId
    const book = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: bookID}, {
        $addToSet: {
            like : authorId
        }
    })
    if (!book) {
        return new NotFoundError(`No Book with id: ${bookID}`)
    }
    await book.save()
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({book})
}
```

This will only add authorId to `like` array of Book if that Id doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setter to create a set-like array:

```
const activity = mongoose.Schema({
   participants : {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed, // Array would probably also work
        required: true,
        set: toSet
   },
   // ... 
}

function toSet(a) {
    return [...new Set(a)];
}
```